# Custom filters field in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have such models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    school_classes = models.ManyToManyField(SchoolClass)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class SchoolClass(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

And I want to modify django admin page for Student in such a way, so I have two selects - one for choosing school and second for choosing classes in that school.

Is there any way to do it without creating custom templates and pages?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to filters results on the `change_list` page or do you want to modify the `change_form` so that one select value is filtered according to another field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I didn't find any simple solutions so I had to rewrite default Django widget for ManyToMany Select.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import Student

class StudentSchoolClassInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Student.school_classes.through

class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [StudentSchoolClassInline]
    exclude = ['student_classes']

admin.site.register(Student, StudentAdmin)
```

[Working with many-to-many models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models).